# Display Part of the output in Browser

Tags: php

**Background** :

I am calling **Soap Url** & getting messages in browser based on **ShipmentNumber**

**Case 1** : When i ran code in **browsers** , For some **ShipmentNumber**   i got below result as output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Transaction] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Reference1] => 10000128254545
            [Reference2] => 
            [Reference3] => 
            [Reference4] => 
            [Reference5] => 
        )

    [Notifications] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

    [HasErrors] => 1
    [ProcessedShipmentHolds] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ProcessedShipmentHold] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 42863418581
                    [HasErrors] => 1
                    [Notifications] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Notification] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Code] => ERR65
                                    [Message] => Hold of the same type already exists
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**Case 2** : For some other **ShipmentNumber** , i got below result :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Transaction] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Reference1] => 10000128254545
            [Reference2] => 
            [Reference3] => 
            [Reference4] => 
            [Reference5] => 
        )

    [Notifications] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

    [HasErrors] => 
    [ProcessedShipmentHolds] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ProcessedShipmentHold] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 42863421156
                    [HasErrors] => 
                    [Notifications] => stdClass Object
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

**Requirement** :

But I want to display only **[Message]** Value in Browser. Means, in Case 1, i want to display "**Hold of the same type already exists**" , in Case 2 , i want to display "**No Message**" in browser....

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    $soapClient = new SoapClient('https://ws.aramex.net/ShippingAPI.V2/Shipping/Service_1_0.svc?wsdl');

    $params = array(
            'ClientInfo'            => array('AccountNumber' => 'IN',                                   
                                    'Version' => 'v1.0'
                                ),

            'Transaction'           => array(
                                        'Reference1'        => '',                                      
                                        'Reference5'        => ''                               
                                    ),

            'ShipmentHolds'=> array(

                            'ShipmentHoldDetails' => array(
                                            'ShipmentNumber' =>'42863421156',
                                            'Comment' =>'test Order'
                                            )
                                            )

    );


    try {
        $auth_call = $soapClient->HoldShipments($params);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($auth_call);
        die();
    } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
        die('Error : ' . $fault->faultstring);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to explain to us what part of implementing your “requirement” you are actually having trouble with.

Comment: please let me know downvote reason, so that i will correct it.....

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your comment, i need to display `part of output` instead of `full output`....

Comment: That is still just your _requirement_, but it does not explain what _problem_ you are having with it. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ This is not a place were you just drop off your requirement, and someone will make it for you.

Comment: @CBroe sorry for that, i will try to update question soon.....

Comment: please provide output as text ?

Comment: Please don't post output as images. Convert it to text.

Comment: @C2486 i updated question, thanks for suggestion.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code. You need to access the right field to display the message.

your message is in:

```
$auth_call->ProcessedShipmentHolds->ProcessedShipmentHold->Notifications->Notification->Message
```

But based on your second question sometimes you don't have it there so go for something like:

```
    if(isset($auth_call->ProcessedShipmentHolds->ProcessedShipmentHold->Notifications->Notification->Message)){
     echo $auth_call->ProcessedShipmentHolds->ProcessedShipmentHold->Notifications->Notification->Message;
    }
     else{
     echo "No Message";
    }
```

You can make it more "elegant" and use ternary operators like

```
isset($auth_call->ProcessedShipmentHolds->ProcessedShipmentHold->Notifications->Notification->Message)?$Message=$auth_call->ProcessedShipmentHolds->ProcessedShipmentHold->Notifications->Notification->Message:$Message='No Message';

echo $Message;
```

Comment: Thanks , now for every `shipment number`, its displaing `No Message`...... but for some `shipment numer`, it should display `Hold of the same type already exists`

Comment: Generally the code checks if the field message exists and if it does it will display it's value (text) otherwise displays No Message. If i my answer, answered your question please mark it as accepted.

Comment: surely i will accept your answer once it worked, but if i use same `shipment number` & if i use code in qiestion, than its displaying as `Hold of the same type already exists` , but if i use your code for same `shipment number` , than its displaying as `no message`, please check this.....

Comment: The paths i used were wrong cause i got them from your image you had before and were different. Corrected my answer. try it now please